# Approximation algorithm for constrained minimization of sub-modular function

Tags: functions, optimization

Given a non-negative, sub-modular function `f`, the objective is to find a set with at exactly `k` elements which minimizes f. I need to prove that for any `ϵ > 0`, there is no algorithm that runs in a sub-exponential running time and is a `(1/3 - ϵ)`-approximation algorithm for the problem.

I tried proving this by contradiction by assuming that an algorithm like that exists but I got no where because I do not know what is the contradiction that I am supposed to arrive to. I also tried to use Chernoff bounds for variables `X1,X2,...Xn` that take either 0 or 1 as values and exactly `k` out of these `n` values are equal to 1 but still could not arrive to a contradiction.

Any help solving this problem will be appriciated!

Comment: Are you working in the value oracle model?

Comment: No. There was no mention on working with it.

Comment: Okay. We typically work in the value oracle model, but we can use explicit function classes too. One more question: are you sure that you don't mean to minimize $f$ subject to a cardinality constraint of *at least* $k$ elements? And are you assuming that $f$ is non-negative? (this last bit is really important for the approximation guarantees that you are seeking)

Comment: Oops! My bad. I contacted my TA and he said that he made a mistake. The solution has to have exactly k elements and yes the function is indeed non- negative. I will correct my question. Thanks for the alert!

Comment: Ah, this is for a class. Okay, what do you know so far / what hardness results have you seen? The hardness for this problem is actually like $O(n / \log n )$ but maybe some simpler proofs can get 1/3. P.S. it'd be good to move this discussion to chat. Not sure how tho.